# Progress Bar won't work for the third download in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webclient

I'm trying to download 4 files simultaneously using 4 webclients. It download all 4 files simultaneously but the progress bar of first two works fine and the third progress bar exactly moves with the 1st one, and the fourth progress bar exactly moves with the 2nd one. Here's my code relevant to the issue.

```
Public WithEvents downloadFile1 As WebClient
Public WithEvents downloadFile2 As WebClient
Public WithEvents downloadFile3 As WebClient
Public WithEvents downloadFile4 As WebClient

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10
End Sub


Private Sub startDownloadFile1()

    downloadFile1 = New WebClient
    Dim targetURL As String = lstURLs.Items.Item(0)
    Dim destinationPath As String = "e:\Downloads\0.jpg"
    downloadFile1.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(targetURL), destinationPath)

End Sub

Private Sub startDownloadFile2()

    downloadFile2 = New WebClient
    Dim targetURL As String = lstURLs.Items.Item(1)
    Dim destinationPath As String = "e:\Downloads\1.jpg"
    downloadFile2.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(targetURL), destinationPath)

End Sub
```

and similler for startDownloadFile3() and startDownloadFile()

```
Private Sub btnDownload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDownload.Click
    startDownloadFile1()
    startDownloadFile2()
    startDownloadFile3()
    startDownloadFile4()
End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile1_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles downloadFile1.DownloadProgressChanged

    pb1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile2_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles downloadFile2.DownloadProgressChanged

    pb2.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile3_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles downloadFile1.DownloadProgressChanged

    pb3.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile4_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles downloadFile2.DownloadProgressChanged

    pb4.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub
```

Comment: what the... I just noticed that thing :/ how on earth did that happen.. let me edit that and try again.. thanks brother, you asked me to add that code :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub downloadFile3_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles **downloadFile1.**DownloadProgressChanged

   pb3.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile4_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles **downloadFile2.**DownloadProgressChanged

    pb4.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
```

Change to: simple error

```
Private Sub downloadFile3_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles **downloadFile3.**DownloadProgressChanged

   pb3.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

End Sub

Private Sub downloadFile4_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Net.DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles **downloadFile4.**DownloadProgressChanged

    pb4.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
```

Comment: oh yes.. working fine now.. thanks :) but how did it even happen? I didn't copy and paste the code, I selected the events.. I guess it shouldn't had happened..